# Is there any problem using Vuejs and JQuery together?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to use **Vue.js** and **JQuery** together in an HTML file. Is there any problems in doing that?

Comment: No there is no big problem, I have used on some of my projects and worked very well.  Instead of that can you describe for what purpose you want to merge both libraries !!!

Comment: Generally there is no issues, but note that *Vue.js* has a lot of the same built in functionality that *JQuery* offers. Generally you should be able to go with *one* of the libraries and not have to mix the two.

Comment: You can use jQuery and Vue together. There are certain tips and tricks that need to be used but they do well together. If you have a certain problem or error that you can't find a resolution for ask. Take a look at this good article explaining this https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are not so many technical issues (although see the comments for more), but it *defeats the point* of using Vue.js.

It would be like trying to use a Fisherprice knife in a sushi kitchen. Yes, it might do something at some point, but it’s going to get in the way the rest of the time.

> Is there any problem using Vuejs and JQuery together?

Simply: yes, there is a problem: it is a bad idea.

*However*, this answer is an opinion and so this question will probably be removed at some point. Don’t feel bad for asking it, but I would beg you to understand why I’m saying it’s a bad idea.